# Mean and median boxplot legend for geom_boxplot in the ggplot2 function

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am attempting to identify the solid black line as the 'median' and the dotted red line as the 'mean'.

However, even when I include `show.legend = TRUE` and `legend.position = "right"`, the legend is not displayed on the graph. I will include a picture below of my boxplot, as it currently is without the legend.

Image description here:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
box %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Total, EX, MD, CI, EI)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill="gray", show.legend = TRUE) +
  labs(x = "Burnout Dimension", y = "Likert Response Count") +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "errorbar", aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..),
               width = .75, linetype = "dashed", color="red") +
  scale_colour_manual("Values", values=c("blue", "red")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(family="Times New Roman",
                            color="#595959",
                            size=14),
        legend.position = "right",
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(c(0,25,50,75,100),
                                          color="#D9D9D9",
                                          size=0.2),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a legend you have to map on aesthetics:

1. Move `color = ...` inside `aes()` and instead of using color names (which are meaningless in this context) use some meaningful label, e.g. `mean` or `median`.
2. To get a legend entry for the median you have to add a second `stat_summary` layer for the median too and get rid of the default median line drawn by `geom_boxplot` using e.g. `fatten = 0`
3. Set your desired colors by making use of a named vector where you use the meaningful labels set in step 1 as names.

As you provided no data I make use of some random fake data:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

box %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Total, EX, MD, CI, EI)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "gray", show.legend = FALSE, fatten = 0) +
  labs(x = "Burnout Dimension", y = "Likert Response Count") +
  stat_summary(
    fun = mean, geom = "errorbar", aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y.., color = "Mean"),
    width = .75, linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun = median, geom = "errorbar", aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y.., color = "Median"),
    width = .75, linetype = "solid"
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual("Values", values = c(Median = "blue", Mean = "red")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(
      family = "Times New Roman",
      color = "#595959",
      size = 14
    ),
    legend.position = "right",
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100),
      color = "#D9D9D9",
      size = 0.2
    ),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(42)

box <- data.frame(
  EX = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
  MD = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
  CI = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
  EI = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
  Total = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```